# Define a bilinear function of strings

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

I have a linear combinations of strings, e.g.

```
combStrings = 0.1 "a" + 0.2 "b"
```

I want to define a function `f[]` which deals with strings in the following way

```
f[combStrings, combStrings] = 0.01 g["a","a"] + 0.02 g["a","b"] +0.02 g["b","a"]  + 0.04 g["b","b"]
```

where `g[string1_,string2_]` is some function dealing with the strings.

Moreover, I want `f[]` to be generalizable to any arbitrary linear combinations of strings, for example for

```
combStrings = 0.1 "a" + 0.2 "b"  + 0.3 "c" + 0.4 "d".
```

I know that I can define linear function on strings like in the following way

```
Fun[c1_?NumberQ h1_?StringQ + c2_?NumberQ h2_?StringQ ] := c1 g[h1] + c2 g[h2]
```

However, I don't know how to define a function satisfying my requirements

Comment: You can do something like `Distribute[g[combStrings, combStrings]]`, along with a definition for `g` to handle `Times[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Outer[g, ##] /. g[a : Times[_, _String] ..] :> 
 Times[Times @@ {a}[[All, 1]], g @@ {a}[[All, 2]]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
f[combStrings, combStrings]
```

> 0.01 g["a", "a"] + 0.02 g["a", "b"] + 0.02 g["b", "a"] +  0.04 g["b", "b"]

```
combStrings2 = 0.1 "a" + 0.2 "b" + 0.3 "c" + 0.4 "d";
f[combStrings2, combStrings2]
```

> 0.01 g[a,a]+ 0.02 g[a,b]+0.03 g[a,c]+0.04 g[a,d]+0.02 g[b,a]+0.04 g[b,b]+0.06 g[b,c]+0.08 g[b,d]+0.03 g[c,a]+0.06 g[c,b]+0.09 g[c,c]+0.12 g[c,d]+0.04 g[d,a]+0.08 g[d,b]+0.12 g[d,c]+0.16 g[d,d]

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[g, f]
f = Module[{h}, h[a_. b_String, c_. d_String] := a c g[b, d]; Plus @@ Tuples @ h @ ##] &;
f[combStrings, combStrings]
```

> 0.01 g["a", "a"] + 0.02 g["a", "b"] + 0.02 g["b", "a"] + 0.04 g["b", "b"]

Answer (score 0):

You can just define rules so that `g` does this automatically:

```
g[a_Plus, b_] := Distribute @ Unevaluated @ g[a,b]
g[a_, b_Plus] := Distribute @ Unevaluated @ g[a,b]

g[a_?NumericQ b_, c_]:=a g[b,c]
g[a_, b_?NumericQ c_]:=b g[a,c]
```

Then:

```
g[.1 "a" + .2 "b", .1 "a" + .2 "b"]
```

> 0.01 g["a", "a"] + 0.02 g["a", "b"] + 0.02 g["b", "a"] + 0.04 g["b", "b"]

and:

```
g[0.1 "a" + 0.2 "b"  + 0.3 "c" + 0.4 "d", 0.1 "a" + 0.2 "b"  + 0.3 "c" + 0.4 "d"]
```

> 0.01 g["a", "a"] + 0.02 g["a", "b"] + 0.03 g["a", "c"] + 0.04 g["a", "d"] + 
>    0.02 g["b", "a"] + 0.04 g["b", "b"] + 0.06 g["b", "c"] + 0.08 g["b", "d"] + 
>    0.03 g["c", "a"] + 0.06 g["c", "b"] + 0.09 g["c", "c"] + 0.12 g["c", "d"] + 
>    0.04 g["d", "a"] + 0.08 g["d", "b"] + 0.12 g["d", "c"] + 0.16 g["d", "d"]